# Hive disable history logs and query logs

Tags: hadoop, hive

We are using hive on our production machines but it generates a lot of job logs in `/tmp/<user.name>/` directory. We would like to disable this logging as we don't need it but can't find any option to disable it. Some of the answers we checked required us to modify **hive-log4j.properties** file. But the only file available in `/usr/lib/hive/conf` is **hive-site.xml**

While starting hive it gives the following information:

```
Logging initialized using configuration in jar:file:/usr/lib/hive/lib/hive-common-0.10.0-cdh4.7.0.jar!/hive-log4j.properties
Hive history file=/tmp/adqops/hive_job_log_79c7f1c2-b4e5-4b7b-b2d3-72b032697bb5_1000036406.txt
```

So it seems that `hive-log4j.properties` file is included in a jar and we can't modify it.

```
Hive Version: hive-hwi-0.10.0-cdh4.7.0.jar
```

Any help/solution is greatly appreciated. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Since Hive expects a custom properties file name, I guess you cannot use the usual trick of setting `-Dlog4j.configuration=my_custom_log4j.properties` on the command-line.

So I fear you would have to **edit `hive-common-xxx.jar` with some ZIP utility** to

1. extract the default props file into `/etc/hive/conf/` or any other
   directory that will be at the head of CLASSPATH
2. delete the file from the JAR
3. edit the extracted file

Ex:

```
$ unzip -l /blah/blah/blah/hive-common-*.jar  | grep 'log4j\.prop'
     3505  12-02-2015 10:31   hive-log4j.properties
$ unzip /blah/blah/blah/hive-common-*.jar hive-log4j.properties -d /etc/hive/conf/
Archive:  /blah/blah/blah/hive-common-1.1.0-cdh5.5.1.jar
  inflating: /etc/hive/conf/hive-log4j.properties
$ zip -d /blah/blah/blah/hive-common-*.jar hive-log4j.properties 
deleting: hive-log4j.properties
$ vi /etc/hive/conf/hive-log4j.properties
```

*NB: proceed at your own risk*...   0:-)

Answer (score 0):

Effectively set the logging level to FATAL

```
hive --hiveconf hive.root.logger=DRFA --hiveconf hive.log.level=FATAL -e "<query>"
```

OR redirect logs into another directory and just purge the dir

```
hive --hiveconf hive.root.logger=DRFA --hiveconf hive.log.dir=./logs --hiveconf hive.log.level=DEBUG -e "<query>"
```

It will create a log file in logs folder. Make sure that the logs folder exist in current directory.